# Launching the windows 10 screen sketch using a command line

Tags: windows-10, command-line, microsoft-surface-pro, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I want to use the windows 10 screen sketch and launch it with a single click. 
I know I can configure the pen to launch it - but that's not good for me. I want to be able to launch it from the Volume up/down keys of the surface itself.

Since it wasn't probably designed for that - I'll settle for running it from a command line (that I'll hook to the volume up button myself)

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

```
ms-penworkspace://Capture
```

Will do what you are after.

(Reference Second Script [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/5ai6v1/lets_share_our_scripts/))

Comment: Link only answer for real!!

Answer (score 3):

With the current insiders fast build (17661) you can also launch screen snipping and then editing with Screen Sketch with just Win+Shift+S. You can launch Screen Sketch itself with `ms-screensketch:`. Same thing you get with Win+Shift+S you can also launch with `ms-screenclip:`.

Comment: Where is the documentation on `ms-screensketch:` and `ms-screenclip:`?

Comment: Official documentation here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-screen-snipping