# Shortcut or script to open Screen Sketch on Win10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Does anyone know a shortcut or even an AutoHotKey script that opens Screen sketch directly? i know that the shortcut Win+W opens Windows Ink Workspace but i have to select screen sketch afterward (which is annoying). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can trigger Screen Sketch by opening `ms-penworkspace://Capture`.

Knowing this, you could create a shortcut to it - for example, on the desktop - and assign that shortcut a shortcut key like so:

[image: Screen sketch shortcut key]

Credit where it's due to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1122538/launching-the-windows-10-screen-sketch-using-a-command-line)

Comment: Good idea with the shortcut. However it only shows the primary display on multi monitor setups. To screen sketch another display, the **Show Windows Ink Workspace button** needs to be checked when right clicking the taskbar. Then launch Screen Sketch with the icon now appearing on other monitor trays. I heard MS is baking it into the Win + Shift + S hotkey in their insider build to replace snipping tool, so hopefully it rolls out soon! The added drawing and annotating tools are awesome.